# Advice for working around my _only_ problem with “with” expressions - accessing success results

Tags: elixir

Consider this code:

```
with {:a, first_result} <- {:a, List.first(["apple"])},
      {:b, b} <- {:b, %{} |> to_string} do
  {:ok, "happy path"}
else
  {:a, _} -> {:error, "this will never be a problem"}
  {:b, error} -> {:error, "Why can I not print #{first_result} here?"}
end
```

I have learned by trial-and-error that this code will *not* return

```
{:error, "Why can I not print apple here?"}
```

as I originally expected from this kind of syntax. Instead, the compiler tells me that `first_result` is not defined in the `else` block. It makes sense, because the "clause chain" returns the error result of the failing clause.

So I have 2 questions:

1. What is the best way to achieve the desired outcome? Should I just use two separate `case` expressions?
2. Imagine if the first clause adds something to the database with `Repo.insert`. Does Ecto know it is inside a `with` expression and wait for all clauses to succeed before committing the transaction? :thinking:  That seems unlikely. So then, why does this expression not allow us to access any successful results?

It seems like I should be very careful when using `with` since, if I understand correctly (I probably don't), I can have "partial success" without being able to see the successful results.

Any advice and insight is welcome! I hope the question is clear.

P.S. I have already read https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1. It just says "the chain is aborted".

Comment: A good question might be why do you need `first_result` in your error?. Maybe `with` is not the best tool for your specific use case? The answer you added solves the problem by including the result at both sides, forcing a match, but it's quite hacky. In the context of Ecto operations a transaction with a [Multi](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#module-example) might be a better fit. Or using the result of the Multi transaction in a `with`. Maybe if you provided an example where you might need the result, more helpful advice could be provided

Comment: @sbacarob Imagine this: clause 1 adds an order to the DB, with validation done on the changeset, clause 2 pays for the order using a 3rd party API. If payment fails, the order has been created and I want to update its state/status to `payment_failed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my question answered here:

https://elixirforum.com/t/advice-for-working-around-my-only-problem-with-with-expressions-accessing-success-results/33720/6

Props to user Bluejay.

In their words, "this works":

```elixir
    with {:a, first_result} <- {:a, List.first(["apple"])},
         {:b, first_result, :something} <- {:b, first_result, :other_thing} do
      {:ok, "happy path"}
    else
      {:a, _} -> {:error, "this will never be a problem"}
      {:b, first_result, _} -> {:error, "Now I can print #{first_result} here"}
    end
```

So the answer is to expand the clause tuples being matched, using variables from previous clause results.